# Reverse the order of rows in bootstrap for mobile devices

Tags: bootstrap-4, rows, reverse

I know it is possible to reverse the order of columns but can it be done with rows using Bootstrap?

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible since the [order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#order) work on any flexbox container...

```
<div class="container d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row order-sm-last order-md-0">
        <div class="col-12">
            row 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            row 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/uG4VTBWWak

Comment: Awesome. Thanks fo the solution.